# How do I add a multi-level column index to an existing df?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, multi-level

How do I add a multi-level column index to an existing df? I read in the df from an Excel file, so I don't want to re-create the df using pd.DataFrame.

Thank you

**Current State**

```
         |Total Assets| AUMs |
Firm 1   | 100        | 300  |
Firm 2   | 200        | 3400 |
Firm 3   | 300        | 800  |
Firm 4   | NaN        | 800  |
```

**Desired State**

```
Importance| H           | H      |
Category | Cat1         | Cat2   |
         |Total Assets  | AUMs   | 
Firm 1   | 100          |  300   |  
Firm 2   | 200          | 3400   |  
Firm 3   | 300          | 800    | 
Firm 4   | NaN          | 800    |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually construct a [`pandas.MultiIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) using one of several constructors. From the docs for your case:

- [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays)
  Convert list of arrays to MultiIndex.
- [`MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples)
  Convert list of tuples to a MultiIndex.
- [`MultiIndex.from_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_frame)
  Make a MultiIndex from a DataFrame.

For your case, I think `pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays` might be the easiest way:

```
df.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['H','H'],['Cat1','Cat2'],df.columns],names=['Importance','Category',''])
```

output:

```
Importance| H           | H      |
Category | Cat1         | Cat2   |
         |Total Assets  | AUMs   | 
Firm 1   | 100          |  300   |  
Firm 2   | 200          | 3400   |  
Firm 3   | 300          | 800    | 
Firm 4   | NaN          | 800    |
```